# relation does not exist - Postgres/docker

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm trying to run the command

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'root2',
  password: 'root2',
  database: 'mycontacts',
});

client.connect();

client.query('SELECT * FROM contacts').then(console.log);
```

but then i got the following error:

```
relation "contacts" does not exist
```

My Postgres code:

```
CREATE DATABASE mycontacts;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories (
  id UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
  id UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR UNIQUE,
  phone VARCHAR,
  category_id UUID,
  FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);
```

and

```
List of relations
 Schema |    Name    | Type  | Owner
--------+------------+-------+-------
 public | categories | table | root2
 public | contacts   | table | root2
(2 rows)
```

I already tried to put the schema before (public.contacts) and double quotes around it but nothing worked. Any tips?

Comment: does selecting from `categories` working?

Comment: No, same thing.

Comment: how is the post related to docker? --- After creating the database, have you set it to be used (`\c mycontacts`)?

Comment: I indeed forgot and i ended up discovering that my database name is other: You are now connected to database "root2" as user "root2". I don't know why but i changed the name on my JS code and now it worked!